# Image editor Applet

Tags: html, images, jquery, flash, silverlight

I'm using codeigniter + jquery on a linux server and i want to integrate in my website a photo/image editor (after that an user have uploaded an image, he must be able to edit it), i need just some simple tools, zoom in and zoom out, brightness and contrast. A good solution may be a java, flash, silverlight applet or something like that.

Any idea?

Tnx Claudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another awesome solution would be Pixlr. It has many photoshop-like features (and I mean MANY - for a web app, that is), and has a decent API. Check it out [here](https://pixlr.com/developer/api/).

And yes, I would, too, stay away from java and silverlight tools. Pixlr would most probably be just fine for any web user.

PS: I think it's better than Picnik (which, if I remember correctly, is now owned by Google).

Answer (score 0):

Picnik has a tool for this.. http://www.picnik.com/
its not the most elegant solution, but sites like constant contact use it for their image editing.

I would stay away from Both Java and Silverlight. Not enough users have the plugins yet for SL, and Java is a joke when it comes to loading on windows. You could use flash for something like this, but then you are really neglecting all those ipad users (all 1% of them!). Picnik is built on flash.